# Proving some simple formula with gamma matrices

Tags: physics, trace

a) Prove that $\text{Tr}(\gamma^5 \not a \not b) = 0,$ where $\not a = a_{\nu}\gamma^{\nu}$.

b) Prove that $\text{Tr}(\gamma^5 \not a \not b \not c \not d) = 4i\epsilon_{\alpha \beta \gamma \delta} a^{\alpha}b^{\beta}c^{\gamma}d^{\delta}$

For (a), I have tried writing $$\text{Tr}(\gamma^5 \gamma^{\mu} \gamma^{\nu}) = \frac{1}{2} \text{Tr}(\left\{\gamma^0, \gamma^1 \gamma^2 \gamma^3 \gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu}\right\}),$$ making use of the explicit form for $\gamma^5 = i\gamma^0 \gamma^1 \gamma^2 \gamma^3$. I played around with shifting the ordering of the terms there (and therefore introducing minus signs) to try and get a result that gave me that $\text{Tr} = - \text{Tr}$ and thus infer it was zero but I have not managed.

Any hints on how to progress?

Thanks!

Comment: Check out the proofs of $5$ and $6$ at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices#Trace_identities.

Comment: Thanks. I don't see what they mean when they say, in proof 5, 'Simply add two factors of $\gamma^\alpha$  with $\alpha$ different from $\mu$ and $\nu$.  Anticommute three times instead of once, picking up three minus signs'? By interchanging $\gamma^{\alpha}$ and $\gamma^{\mu}$, we also get a metric factor since in general $\left\{\gamma^{\mu}, \gamma^{\nu}\right\} = 2g^{\mu \nu}$.

Comment: With $\alpha$ different from $\mu$ and $\nu$, you don't get metric factors, since the anti-commutator for different indices vanishes (since the metric tensor for different indices vanishes).

Comment: But why can we say that $\alpha$ is not $\mu$ or $\nu$? I mean in $\not a$, there is a sum $a_o \gamma^0 + a_1\gamma^1 + ..$ and since $\mu \in [0,3]$, at some point $\alpha=\mu$?

Comment: Funny, I just got out of the shower, and in the shower I was thinking about what might be throwing you off, and I was thinking that it's probably the summation :-) Note that the equation is claimed to hold for arbitrary $a$ and $b$, which requires that it holds for each pair of $\mu,\nu$ individually, so what you need to show is $\operatorname{Tr}\gamma^5\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu=0$ for arbitrary $\mu$ and $\nu$, even without summation. For each particular pair of $\mu,\nu$, you can choose $\alpha$ different from both.

Comment: :) I think I understand what you mean, although I have done similar exercises and always used the metric to get the answer. For example, $\gamma^{\mu} \not a \not b \not c \gamma_{\mu} = a_{\nu}b_{\sigma}c_{\rho} \gamma^{\mu} \gamma^{\nu} \gamma^{\sigma} \gamma^{\rho} \gamma_{\mu}$. The first step was to swap $\mu$ and $\nu$ but that involved me introducing the metric. It seems to me you are saying that $\mu$ and $\nu$ can be treated to be different and thus no need for the metric?

Comment: If they're the same, then $\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu=\gamma^\mu\gamma^\mu=1$, so in that case the trace is just that of $\gamma^5$, which is zero.

Comment: That's also what I understand from what is written in proof 6,  'anticommutation rules imply that interchanging two of the indices changes the sign of the trace', i.e swapping any two of $\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu} \gamma^{\alpha}\gamma^{\delta}$ does not introduce a metric just a sign

Comment: I think the argument in proof $6$ is that if any two indices are the same, we can make the corresponding matrices adjacent by commutation, then cancel them and then invoke the proof of $5$, so the only non-zero case is the one where all four indices are different, and yes, in this case you again only get signs and no metrics when commuting.

Comment: Ok I think I am seeing it now.  Everything that has been said makes sense to me, I am just trying to connect it to what I did in previous exercises where I did use the metric.  E.g when I wanted to compute $\gamma^{\mu} \not a \not b \gamma_{\mu}$ (no traces involved this time), I wrote it as $a_{\nu}b_{\sigma} \gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu}\gamma^{\sigma}\gamma_{\mu}$ and interchanged the mu and nu terms there but I used the metric in doing so, I didn't make any argument as to whether they might be the same or not. I just took the general case. I guess what is done above is we have considered ..

Comment: ...separate cases? one case where the indices are equal and others when they not?

Comment: I don't think you need to distinguish those cases -- my remark about a simpler proof when $\mu=\nu$ was a bit misleading -- you can also use the same proof as for $\mu\neq\nu$; it's only necessary that $\alpha\neq\mu$ and $\alpha\neq\nu$, since you only want to commute $\gamma^\alpha$ with everything else, you're not commuting $\gamma^\mu$ with $\gamma^\nu$.